# go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory

Tags: go

Buenas se que esta pregunta se hizo varias veces, pero ninguna de las soluciones que brindaban me sirvieron, estoy haciendo el tutorial de go, y en la sección

> llamar codigo de otro modulo

me da el error que esta en el titulo.

```
<myproject>/
 |-- greetings/
 |-- hello/
```

dentro de **greetings** tengo los archivos go.mod y greetings.go
dentro de **hello** se encuentran los archivos go.mod y hello.go

**codigo hello**

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"example.com/greetings"
)

func main(){
  message:= greetings.Hello("x")
  fmt.Println(message)
}
```

dentro de la carpeta **hello** escribi el siguiente comando
`go mod edit -replace example.com/greetings=../greetings` y luego de ejecutarlo escribi

```
go mod tidy
```

y al verificarl el archivo go.mod de hello/ me aparecio lo siguiente

**hello/go.mod**

```
module example.com/hello

go 1.21.6

replace example.com/greetings => ../greetings

require example.com/greetings v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
```

segun el tutorial al ejecutar el archivo hello.go de la carpeta hello, ya deberia poder ejecutar la funcion que estoy importando desde greetings/greetings.go
pero en la consola me tira el error **go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory**

aun copiando y pegando el codigo provisto por la documentacion oficial de go sigo teniendo ese error,

Aviso: en el archivo greetings/greetings.go tengo todo el codigo implementado, no lo copie aca para no hacer tan extenso la pregunta